# error: "No objects or images to bake"

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to bake my AO map and every time I click bake, I get the error: "No objects or images to bake".

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh is the active object, but not currently selected in object mode. Switch to object mode and select the object, then click bake. It should work fine now.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman! Thank you